# Dynamic setTimeout causes "maximum call stack exceeded" error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create setTimeout that will call function and then function will call setTimeout again but with different interval value.

The issue is that it seems to fall into infinite loop.

These are starting variables:

```
var interval = 1500;
var elapsed = 0;
var totalTimer = 40000;
var startTime = null;
```

This is the function:

```
function playLights(){
        startTime = Date.now();
        interval = (totalTimer-elapsed) * 0.026;
        lights[0].color(0, 91, 68, 3500, 0);
        lights[1].color(0, 91, 68, 3500, 0);
        setTimeout(function(){
            lights[0].color(0, 100, 100, 3500, 0);
            lights[1].color(0, 100, 100, 3500, 0);
        }, 300);
        elapsed = Date.now() - startTime;
        if((Date.now() - startTime) < 37000){
            setTimeout(playLights(), interval.toFixed());
        }
        console.log("Interval: "+interval+" ,Elapsed: "+elapsed);
    }
```

When action happens I call `playLights();`

What's supposed to happen:

1) Bomb gets planted in game,

2) It must call playLights(),

3) It must get current time and save it,

4) It must determine interval, so since it's first call - it must be 1040 ms.

5) It must flicker colors. (Not important right now)

6) Then it must calculate how much time elapsed based on currentDate - storedDate.

7) Then it must check if elapsed time is more than 37000 ms (37 seconds)

If yes - setTimeout on itself.

If not - just nothing.

I keep getting maximum call stack exceeded by Node.js

Did I make mistake somewhere which causes it to fall into infinite loop?

Comment: `setTimeout(playLights(),` should be `setTimeout(playLights,` - you are running the method and passing its result, rather than passing it as a reference, to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard brilliant, thank you. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code, for example 
 In your function you set `startTime` to `Date.now()` it's alright, BUT! at the very next moment you set `elapsed` to `Date.now() - startTime` so it will be always `0`, because `startTime` equals `Date.now()`.
 Then you just do the same thing in the statement of your `if` section, it will be always true.
  SO basicly nothing changes, and that leads to an infinite loop etc..
 Either you can set `startTime` in your main function, or pass it thru `playLights()` function.
 Finally you have to pass `startTime` to the `callback` function in `setTimeout()` you can do it like so:

```
`setTimeout(function() {playLights(startTime);}, interval.toFixed());`
```

so your code would look something like this:

```
function playLights(startTime) {
    interval = (totalTimer-elapsed) * 0.026;
    lights[0].color(0, 91, 68, 3500, 0);
    lights[1].color(0, 91, 68, 3500, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
        lights[0].color(0, 100, 100, 3500, 0);
        lights[1].color(0, 100, 100, 3500, 0);
    }, 300);
    elapsed = Date.now() - startTime;
    if (elapsed < 37000) {
        setTimeout(function(){playLights(startTime)}, interval.toFixed());
    }
    console.log("Interval: "+interval+" ,Elapsed: "+elapsed);
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
playLights(Date.now());
```